# Does WSO2 Identity Server support SAML Artifact Binding Federation?

Tags: wso2, federation, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to integrate WSO2 Identity Server with a Mock SAML2 Identity Provider.
Currently the Mock SAML 2.0 Identity Provider only support SAML Artifact binding.

I have configured a federated SAML 2.0 Web SSO base on the guide found from this link:
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-saml-2.0-web-sso/

The WSO2is as Service provider is able to redirect the user to the Mock SAML 2.0 Identity provider and after successful authentication with the Mock SAML 2.0 Identity Server, the Mock SAML 2.0 Identity Server  need to redirect to a endpoint at WSO2is with the "?SAMLart=" support.

After looking around, the default https://localhost:9443/acs does not support "?SAMLart=".

May I ask does wso2is support this type of setup?

Thank You.

Comment: Did you try the stuff in this doc?
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/configuring-saml-2.0-artifact-binding/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for sharing this link. The implementation I am looking for is to use wso2is as OIDC Provider with PKCE support with saml 2.0 federation with 3rd party identity Server that only support SAML Artifact Binding for my Angular application. Using the built-in authentication I am able to authenticate via OIDC code flow with PKCE. Now I am stuck with integrating SAML 2.0 artifact binding federation for authentication

Comment: What you are trying to do is that configuring an external IDP with WSO2 Identity Server with SAML artifact binding? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yup, you are correct. WSO2is as Service Provider and a federated external IDP with SAML Artifact Binding. As of now the WSO2is is able to generate the SAML request to my external IDP. But when the SAML 2 external IDP is redirecting back, it append the "SAMLart=" query string which need to be processed by WSO2is Service Provider. The /acs endpoint on WSO2is doesn't accept SAMLart but "SAMLResponse=" query string. I have tried other products such as IdentityServer4 with SAML2P plugin but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I hope this will help you. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/configuring-federated-authentication/

Comment: Did you try enabling "Enable Artifact Binding" config in SAML 2 federated authenticator configs of the IDP? And the ACS URL should be https://localhost:9443/commonauth

Comment: Hi  @MadurangaSiriwardena ,
I have enabled "Enable Artifact Binding" checkbox in the SAML 2 federated authentcator config for IDP. According to this page: [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Login+to+Identity+Server+Using+Another+Identity+Server+-+OAuth2) the /commonauth endpoint is callback for OAuth/OIDC.
I have tried and it throws "Authenitcation Error! Something went wrong during the authentication process. Please try signing in again."
If I disable federated Authentication, the built-in authentication works, but not something I am looking for.
Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: For all the protocols, the callback is the same. Do you see any error logs on the IS side and federated IDP side? If not try enabling debug logs and see if there is any useful information printed.